# I tried creating a function to concatinate str2 to str1 using pointers but it doesn't work as I am expecting

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

I was making an `strcat` using pointers in C, however I encountered the following problem in my `while` loop.

This is my code which fails to add str2 (here `t`) to str1 (here `s`):

```c
char *pstrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    char *start=s;
    while(*s++)
        ;
    while(*s++=*t++){
        ;
    }
    return start;
}
```

My main code was:

```c
int main()
{
    char s[35]=" hi nice to meet you ";
    char t[]="ho";
    printf("%s",pstrcat(s,t));
    return 0;
}
```

Expectations:
I was expecting a output of  `hi nice to meet you ho` but instead got  `hi nice to meet you`.

However when I changed the `while` loop (first `while` loop of `pstrcat`) a little bit it started to work.
The new `while` loop looked like:

```c
while(*s!='\0')
    s++;
```

Problem in brief:
I was unable to understand the difference of the two loops. I think both of them should work since both of them must be ending at `'\0'` with address of `s` currently pointing to `'\0'`.
However I must be wrong if my code isn't working.

Comment: Remember that your destination array should have enough space to accommodate additional chars.

Comment: @Karthick I just gave changed char s[] to char s[35] but it still didn't work for this case.

Comment: After your first while loop ends, `s` will be pointing to next position after '\0'.

Comment: So either do `s--` after first while loop or rewrite the first while loop as `while(*s)
    s++;`

Comment: thanks that worked and I understand where I was wrong as well

Comment: You should make the change to using `char s[35];` in your posted code. Otherwise, the answer is just that you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Good. Please create an answer. @Zolo_Ryan

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the code.

1. Destination array does not have enough space to accommodate additional chars.
2. First while loop in `pstrcat` moves the pointer beyond `\0`

```
   while(*s++)
        ;
```

It can be rewritten as

```
while(*s)
   s++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't know if one character array is big enough to fit both strings in so it's safer to create a new one but you must remember to free it after you've done with it. To concatenate two null-terminated strings, you could do the following...

```
char *pstrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    char *start=malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1);
    sprintf(start, "%s%s%c", s, t, 0);
    return start;
}

int main()
{
    char s[]=" hi nice to meet you \0";
    char t[]="ho\0";
    char *st = pstrcat(s,t);
    printf("%s",st);
    free(st);
    return 0;
}
```