# Function that returns a string that is the concatenation of two strings given in input

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

i've been tasked with writing a C program that recieves in input two strings (I can decide their content during the decleration) and returns a third string that is the concatenation of the two previous strings.

Moreover, I also need to replace each vowel of the third string with a star symbol '*'.

The main difficulty that i'm encountring is how to return a string from a function that takes in input two strings.
A correction of my faulty code would also be much appreciated :)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* concatvow (char *str1, char *str2);

int main()
{
    char word1[20]="One plus one ";
    char word2[20]="eqauls two";
    char *word3[20];
    
    concatvow(word1, word2);
    
    printf("%s", *word3);
    return 0;
}

const char* concatvow (char *str1, char *str2){

    char strfinal[20];
    int i=0;
    
    strcat(str1, str2);
    
    strcpy(strfinal, str1);
    
    if(strfinal[i]==65 || strfinal[i]==69 || strfinal[i]==73 || strfinal[i]==79 || strfinal[i]==85)            {
       strfinal[i]='*';
    }

return strfinal;
}
```

This is the output of my code.

```
main.c: In function ‘concatvow’:
main.c:33:8: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   33 | return strfinal;
      |        ^~~~~~~~


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: As the warning suggests, you can't return the address of a local variable, because that memory will no longer belong to the local variable as soon as you return from the method. You need to *either* pass in the target location to fill *or* use `malloc` (or equivalent) to allocate on-heap memory for the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: function returns address of local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380758/error-function-returns-address-of-local-variable)

Comment: Yeah, I understand my error now, I now need to store the return value inside a variable that can be printed out.

Comment: And this: 'strcat(str1, str2);' blows str1.

Comment: This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927732/i-tried-creating-a-function-to-concatinate-str2-to-str1-using-pointers-but-it-do/74928275#74928275.

Answer (score 1):

Any variable in C only holds in a memeory within a certain scope. As stated by a previous answer, the memory you are returning does not belong to that variable anymore. You could use heap memory with malloc.

```c
 char *strfinal = malloc (sizeof (char) * 20);
```

Comment: I understand now, it no longer gives me that error.
Could you kindly give me some insight on how I can store the return value of that function inside a variable (word3) so I can print out later?

I know how to do it with integers but not with strings. I tried to do:
word3[20] = concatvow(word1, word2); 
C dosen't allow this, I've read some posts about it but I failed to implement the solution into my problems.
Thanks for your kind and fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of warning:

Variable `strfinal` is local non-static variable of `concatvow()` function which will cease to exist once returned from `concatvow()` function. Any attempt to access it outside of its lifetime lead to undefined behaviour.

Few other problem in your code:

1. Check this statement of `concatvow()` function -

   ```
      strcat(str1, str2);
   ```

- This will result in undefined behaviour if `str1` will not have enough space to hold the resultant string after concatenation.
- Even if `str1` will have enough space, it will result in modifying `str1`. Is that intended?
- If string literals passed to `concatvow()` function in place of array, it will attempt to modify the string literal which is something not recommended.

2. Check for lower case vowels is missing while replacing vowels with `'*'` character.

Handling all these scenarios:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char * concatvow (const char *str1, const char *str2);

int main (void) {
    char word1[20] = "One plus one ";
    char word2[20] = "eqauls two";

    const char * word3 = concatvow (word1, word2);

    if (word3) {
        printf ("Result : %s\n", word3);
        free ((char *)word3);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

const char * concatvow (const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    if (!str1 || !str2) {
        // add error handling
        return NULL;
    }

    char * strfinal = malloc (strlen (str1) + strlen (str2) + 1); // +1 for null terminating character

    if (!strfinal) {
        // add error handling
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // combine str1 and str2 and create one string
    sprintf (strfinal, "%s%s", str1, str2);

    // replace each vowel with a star symbol '*'
    for (char * p = strfinal; *p; ++p) {
        if (*p == 'A' || *p == 'a' ||
            *p == 'E' || *p == 'e' ||
            *p == 'I' || *p == 'i' ||
            *p == 'O' || *p == 'o' ||
            *p == 'U' || *p == 'u') {
            *p = '*';
        }
    }

    return strfinal;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Result : *n* pl*s *n* *q**ls tw*
```